# Ion-slide-box using button instead of swiping

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I am trying to use a button in order to navigate through the slides however it does not work. I have done this so far:

HTML:

```
  <ion-slide-box>
    <ion-slide>
        <button ng-click="slide()">Next</button>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        This is the next slide
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slide-box>
```

JS:

```
function controllerClass($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
  $scope.slide = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    console.log("Click");
  }
}
```

It shows the log "Click" but I don't know what is wrong with the slider itself.

I could really use help.

Comment: Did you really only have one slide?

Comment: Maybe try setting a handle id `<ion-slide-box delegate-handle="test">` and in your controller: `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('test').next();`

Comment: I'm sorry for my late answer as I was busy. For now I am just trying to navigate next/previous and I am trying to get to slide 2 to begin with.

Comment: And for the suggestion using delegate-handle it gives me a message in the console about using $timeout I've tried to put the ionic next method inside a timeout but couldn't get it to work unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a small demo for you

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/bohp5n?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <a ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-class="{'active': $index === current}" ng-click="slide($index)" class="button button-stable">{{ button.name }}</a>
</div>
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" slide-interval="1000" does-continue="true">
    <ion-slide>
        <div class="box" style="text-align:center;">
            First slide
        </div>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <div class="box" style="text-align:center;">
                Second slide
            </div>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

**Contoller**

```
 $scope.buttons = [{
     name: '1'
 }, {
     name: '2'
 }];

 $scope.slide = function($index) {
     $scope.current = $index;
     $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide($index);
 }
```

If you need any additional feature.Please let me know?

Comment: Your Plunker works nice. However it says that "to" is not defined. Did I miss out something?

Comment: Did not work :( What about your "slideHasChanged" shall that one not be defined in the controller as well? Maybe that is what I am missing?

Comment: @NSaa  There is no need of defining slideHasChanged() method.Because it is the part of <ion-slide-box> dirctive

Comment: I get no errors and the log is still saying the "Click". I don't know what I am doing wrong but something is wrong with me

Comment: Ah okay I see regarding the slideHasChanged

Comment: Can you create a plunker demo?

Comment: I am at work right now. I really appreciate your help. Do you have time later?

Comment: @NSaa If the answer help you.Could you please accept my answer

Comment: @NSaa :Sure.If you have any doubt.Please let me know

Comment: Thanks you can delete now :) I have written it down this time hehe

Comment: @NSaa :Always Welcome

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({ selector: 'page-calender', templateUrl: 'calender.html' }) 
export class CalenderPage {
    @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;
    constructor() {}
    gotoNextSlide() { this.slides.slideNext(); }
    gotoPrevSlide() { this.slides.slidePrev(); }
}
```

Comment: actually i ajust copy my code , import Viewchild and Slides then write code as above using Viewchid create the child of slides it would be use in function as i create two function goToNextSlide() and goToPrevSlide in html code just use click function with prev. and next button like this 
(click)="goToNextSlide()" same for prev. button

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a late answer, but I've been struggling with this component for a while.
You can also call the slider methods directly, when initialized, just store the slider object inside your controller and then use it:
The HTML:

```
        <ion-slides
            options="ctrl.slideOptions"
            slider="ctrl.slider"
            style="margin: -13px 0 0; height: 19.1em;">
            <ion-slide-page
                ng-repeat="b in ctrl.slideCollection"
                ng-click="transCtrl.selectSlide(b)">
                <!-- slide content here -->
            </ion-slide-page>
            <div class="swiper-button-next icon ion-chevron-right" ng-click="ctrl.slideNext($event)"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev icon ion-chevron-left" ng-click="ctrl.slidePrev($event)"></div>
        </ion-slides>
```

And the JS:

```
ctrl.slideOptions = {
    loop: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    pagination: false,
    effect: 'coverflow',
    coverflow: {
        rotate: 50,
        stretch: 0,
        depth: 100,
        modifier: 1,
        slideShadows : false
    }
};

$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.sliderInitialized", function(event, data){
    // data.slider is the instance of Swiper
    ctrl.slider = data.slider;
    ctrl.activeIndex = 0;
});

$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeStart", function(event, data){
    console.log('Slide change is beginning');
});

$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeEnd", function(event, data){
    // note: the indexes are 0-based
    ctrl.activeIndex = data.slider.activeIndex;
    ctrl.previousIndex = data.slider.previousIndex;
});
ctrl.slideNext = function($event) {
    ctrl.slider.onClickNext($event);
}
ctrl.slidePrev = function($event) {
    ctrl.slider.onClickPrev($event);
}
```

The ng-click part is not always necessary, but if things do not work as expected it's nice to have a workaround.

I also have a tweak for the CSS buttons:

```
.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
    background: none;
}
```

Use it if you like Ionic icons better than the swiper ones (ugly blue caret...)